# D3.js Pie Chart transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

[Here is a link to the CodePen](http://codepen.io/jacob_johnson/pen/GqYNQB?editors=0010)

I have a pie chart that has it's data changed when a setting is changed (right now my data is just randomly picked but my official document properly does this). My problem is that I don't understand updating the pie chart using a transition.

This is the process for creating the pie chart:

```
function createPieChart()
{
  var width = 320,
      height = 320,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#0083CB", "#006BA5", "#00527f"]);

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);

  var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 40)
  .innerRadius(radius - 40);

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

  data = updateData();

  var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

  g.append("path")
    .attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });

  g.append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });

  function type(d) {
    d.population = +d.population;
    return d;
  }
}
```

This is my function for updating the pie chart. I get an error `ReferenceError: s is not defined` that appears to come from the D3 lib:

```
function updatePieChart()
{
  svg.selectAll("path").data(pie(data)).transition().duration(500)
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);
}
```

And the arcTween function:

```
function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) { return arc(i(t));    };
}
```

Any help would be great. When I search I only find donut pie charts unfortunately.

Thank you.

Comment: Your variable `s` doesn't exist within the scope of `updateDegrees()`. What is `s` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a little bit. Look at [this](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) tutorial to understand how enter, update and exit selection works. Also, don't use two libraries. You can achieve, your requirement with d3 alone.
Hope this helps.

```js
var data = [];
var targetDegree = [ "Associate degree", "Bachelors degree" ];

var width = 320,
      height = 320,
      radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#0083CB", "#006BA5", "#00527f"]);

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);

  var labelArc = d3.svg.arc()
  .outerRadius(radius - 40)
  .innerRadius(radius - 40);

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) { return d.population; });

  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")"); 
 
function updateData()
{ 
 
  var outweigh = Math.random() * 100,
      not_outweigh = Math.random() * 100,
      same = Math.random() * 100;    

  var data = [
    { age: "outweigh", population: outweigh },
    { age: "does not", population: not_outweigh },
    { age: "same", population: same }
  ];

  return data;
}
updatePieChart();
 
function updateDegrees(s)
{
  var index = targetDegree.indexOf(s); // Check existence
  if (index > -1) // Already exists and needs to be removed
    targetDegree.splice(index, 1);
  else           // Doe snot exist so should be added
  {
   targetDegree.push(s);
  }
  updatePieChart();
}

$("#bachelor_check").change(function() {
  updateDegrees("Bachelors degree");
});

$("#associate_check").change(function() {
  updateDegrees("Associate degree");
});

$('#majors_sel').on('change', function() {
  updatePieChart();
});

function updatePieChart()
{
 data = updateData();
 var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data));

 var arcpaths = g.enter().append('g').attr('class','arc');
 
 arcpaths.append('path').attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });
 arcpaths.append('text').attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });
 
 
 g.exit().remove(); 
 
 var arcpaths = g.select('path').attr("d", arc)
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.age); });
 
 var arctext = g.select("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + labelArc.centroid(d) + ")"; })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.age; });
 

  function type(d) {
    d.population = +d.population;
    return d;
  }
} 


function arcTween(a) {
  var i = d3.interpolate(this._current, a);
  this._current = i(0);
  return function(t) { return arc(i(t));    };
}
```

```css
.arc text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
    text-anchor: middle;
  }

  .arc path {
    stroke: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='majors_sel'>
    <option value="All">All majors</option>
    <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
    <option value="Life sciences">Life sciences</option>
    <option value="Physical sciences/math">Physical sciences/math</option>
    <option value="Health">Health</option>
    <option value="Education">Education</option>
    <option value="Business/management">Business/management</option>
    <option value="Computer/information sciences">Computer/information sciences</option>
    <option value="Law">Law</option>
    <option value="Social/behavioral sciences">Social/behavioral sciences</option>
    <option value="Humanities">Humanities</option>
    <option value="Vocational/technical training">Vocational/technical training</option>
    <option value="Undeclared">Undeclared</option>
    <option value="Other (Please specify):">Other</option>
  </select>

  <div id='degree_check'>
    <label>
      <input id='bachelor_check' type='checkbox' name='degree' value='Bachelors degree' checked>
    Bachelors</label>
    <label>
      <input id='associate_check' type='checkbox' name='degree' value='Associate degree' checked>
    Associate</label>
  </div>
```